# Have a Couple of questions about Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am new to Ubuntu and I have a couple of questions.

How can you sharpen text on Ubuntu?

How can you move applications from the task bar to the desktop ?

How can I make the shut down/ power off button more visible. Like being able to see it on the top bar than having to go to a menu

Thank You

Comment: So essentially you want to know if there are accessibility options available ? Yes. There are zooming utility, screen reader, theme can be changes to high contrast.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to Ubuntu!  there are a few UI designs, but im guessing you have the ever popular Gnome

**For text :**
Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool
```

Once you have it under advanced settings, there is a "fonts section

**To move applications to the desktop:**

First off As a linux user, I recommend using the terminal and get used to not using the desktop!  A better alternative is downloading Cairo-dock

If you must, and this goes against most linux users beliefs,

First copy your desired application's icon from the /usr/share/applications directory to Desktop,

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/filename.desktop ~/Desktop
```

Then change the permissions(give execute permission to the .desktop file) of copied .desktop file on the Desktop,

```
sudo chmod +x ~/Desktop/filename.desktop
```

Double click on the application icon to run it's corresponding application.

**Power button:**

Again most users use the terminal, and not buttons.  Its traditional and faster.  Learn these

```
sudo reboot (restart)
sudo shutdown -h now 
sudo shutdown -P now
sudo poweroff (shutdown)
sudo halt -p
sudo init 0
```

I dont know if there is a way to change the top launcher, as that is part of the ubuntu file structure and cannot be changed.

Comment: By any chance do you know how to fix Ubuntu 14.04 when it freezes when I start the computer and use it for a couple of minutes it freezes and everything does not move

Comment: There has been a bug known to the community, often times it will kick you off to login screen after 2 mins logged on.  I would do a sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Also this...   sudo chown user /home/user/.Xauthority, where user is your username.

Comment: Might be graphics card issue. Id suggest to try different desktop environment such as gnome,xfce,or lxde

Comment: I have a NVidia graphics card

Comment: @AlanAlex: Please don't ask new questions in the comments, but just [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).  Furthermore, If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the "1" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...

Comment: please select me as write answer if I did it correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `unity` as you desktop environment, you install `unity tweak-tool`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Once you install it, search for it in dash (dash opens once you press `super/windows` key) and click on it to open it.

In `unity tweak-tool` you can change your desktop themes, fonts etc.

To get shortcuts in your desktop, you can read  [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop) .